# Angular 6 Material - Component is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am trying to install Material Design in my Angular 6 app. I added Navigation schematic using the command `ng generate @angular/material:nav myNav`. When I compile and serve the app, I am getting error as

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   'my-nav' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'my-nav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

**My code for app.modules.ts is as follow:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MyNavComponent } from './my-nav/my-nav.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyNavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**My Code for app.component.html is as follows:**

```
<my-nav></my-nav>
```

Please let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Can you add the `@Component`-part of your ./my-nav/my-nav.component.ts?

Comment: ` @Component({
  selector: 'app-my-nav',
  templateUrl: './my-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-nav.component.css'],
}) `

Comment: Your html should be using `<app-my-nav>` instead of `<my-nav>` then

Comment: Done! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-nav',
  templateUrl: './my-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-nav.component.css']
})
```

Your selector is `app-my-nav`, therefore it is `<app-my-nav></app-my-nav>`:

> [`selector`](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector) identifies this directive in a template and triggers instantiation of
>   the directive.